# Ajax not recognized in JQuery file

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, html

I uploaded to GitHub days ago an MVC project, I've downloaded it again, and want to set some new functions using JQuery Ajax, but now when I'm trying to do something like this:

```
$("#btnTrigger").click(function () {   
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "/Orders/MyJson/"
    }).success(function (result) {
        alert(result.testing)
    })
});
```

An exception is thrown: `Object doesn't support property or method 'success'`.
I think that something is wrong with JQuery, when I'm going to write `$.ajax` inside a function the keyword `ajax` is not displayed, instead Intellisense shows other keywords like `attr` etc. Normally the keyword `ajax` is displayed from Intellisense.
I've been trying uninstaling and installing JQuery again and nothing happened, I've check the BundleConfig class to check if the JQuery files are added and they are there, I've installed unobtrusive ajax and have added it to BundleConfig class too and still the problem continues... What it could be??

Comment: Nothing wrong with jQuery...your implementation is wrong. Read the docs http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @charlietfl  It worked putting the `success` inside, but why??? I've been using the other way and always worked good on my ajax calls. And why Intellisense doesn't show the ajax keyword like in other projects?

Comment: can't possibly use it the  way you have shown... `$.ajax` returns  a deferred object which has no `success` and that is confirmed by your error

Comment: @charlietfl Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

Comment: It seems that I've been using it with old versions of JQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this, putting the success inside ajax definition

```
$("#btnTrigger").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "/Orders/MyJson/",
            success: {
                function (result) {
                alert(result.testing);
            }
        }})})
```

Comment: It worked putting the `success` inside, but why??? I've been using the other way and always worked good on my ajax calls. And why Intellisense doesn't show the ajax keyword like in other projects?

Comment: To be honest, I've always used it this way and didn't know of another. Maybe you had some other script loaded which extended the ajax. Since it helped, can you please mark my answer as accepted? Thanks.

Comment: Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead. –

Comment: I've been using in other versions probably... The .success() is deprecated from JQuery 3.0 on, instead of .success() we could use .done() although I'll begin to use it with the success inside the ajax curly braces :)